# What goes on when you define a variable in a loop in C?

Tags: c, memory

If I have a for loop:

```
for (uint8_t x = 0; x < 100; ++x) {

    char f[2000] = {0,};
}
```

what actually is going on here? Is this reusing the same memory address every time so it only actually allocates it once, or is it using a new memory location each loop? Does it depend on optimization levels? What about the implementation?

Comment: Under most optimization levels, the loop shown would be optimized away completely.  The body of the loop does nothing with the variable `f` and there are no side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that `f` is allocated in the same memory address every time around the loop, but it should be very hard to find a compiler that doesn't do it that way. I have seen `f` get trashed in the loop iteration, so yes it really does go out of scope at the closing brace.

A modern compiler will almost always gather up all the variable declarations within a function, analyze for overlapping runtime scope (not compile time--It's smart enough now to figure out when a variable isn't used any further down in the function most of the time), and allocate all the fixed* memory on the stack at function entry time. This runtime call is still *much* cheaper than `malloc()`.

Stack allocation is done with a single instruction for all the variables: `sub rbp, constant`. Freeing the memory is done the same way: `add rbp, constant`. This buffer is almost half the size (4KB) where the compiler has to emit a call to the runtime to verify the stack has enough room. On Windows, this function is called `_chkstk`.

*Flexible arrays are allocated with a stretchy stack element near their first use.

Comment: it is 2000 bytes no? 4kb = 4000 bytes and i defined the buffer to be 2000 bytes

Comment: @user18043747: Oops my eyes fooled me I thought I was looking at a 20kb buffer.

Comment: so would the runtime call still be made?

Comment: @user18043747: Need to see the whole function. If that's your only buffer, then no.

Comment: the buffer is populated, then some strstr checks are done, then the loop iteration ends

Answer (score 0):

When one iteration of the loop ends and a new one begins, the lifetime of the array `f` ends and the lifetime of a new array `f` starts.  As far as the C standard is concerned, each is distinct from the other.

In practice, the compiler may use the same memory address for each iteration of `f` or it might not.  This is not something that can be depended on.  Certain optimizations may take advantage of the fact that the lifetime of `f` ends at the end of the loop body and do things that appear strange in non-compliant code.

In short, stick with what the C standard says is valid and don't make any assumptions about `f`.